Why does this pair measurement scheme for surface code works?
I found this measurement scheme for surface code, from some paper, and it goes like this: Suppose we want to measure a weight 4 X stabilizer from the surface code:
The initial stabilizers are X1X2X3X4, and we have two ancillas initialized as Za, Zb.
The measurement sequence is:

X1Xa, X4Xb
ZaZb,
X2Xa,X3Xb
Za, Zb

What puzzles me is that because of the measurements, the logical operators will be updated by the measurements, and if there is a measurement error, this may lead to an undetectable logical error.
For example, when measuring the stabilizer X1X2X3X4, using ancilla ZaZb, with logical Z representative restricted to these qubits being Z1Z3, the logical representative will change dynamically: Z1Z3->Z1Z3Za->Z1Z3Zb. However, the ZZ measurements are not involved in any detector cells, which means that if there is a measurement error on any of the ZZ or Z measurements, the logical operator will acquire a sign flip (hence a logical error) that is undetectable.
So I am wondering if this scheme is fault tolerant? Or if there is anything that I am missing out on.

An individual measurement like this won't be "fault tolerant", that's a property of a whole system using the measurements. For the individual measurement you just want to know that it is correctly implementing the operation.
For an $M_{XXXX}$ measurement the required flows are that individual X terms should go through, pairs of Z terms should go through, and you should learn the measurement result:
X___ -> X___
_X__ -> _X__
__X_ -> __X_
___X -> ___X
ZZ__ -> ZZ__
_ZZ_ -> _ZZ_
__ZZ -> __ZZ
XXXX -> m

The easiest way to check this is to convert the circuit into a ZX graph, knowing that two-qubit B-basis measurement is a vertical edge between B-basis nodes and B-basis reset/measure is a leaf node of the opposite basis. You then confirm it has the flows, by following the rule that a flow must touch an even number of a node's edges when their bases match and must touch all or none of a node's edges when their bases differ:

You can also just keep applying spider fusion to the graph and it will collapse into the "usual" representation of a multi-qubit X product measurement, proving it's a multi-qubit X product measurement.
Alternatively, you can use stim.Circuit.flow_generators to get flows of the circuit and perform Gaussian elimination to show they include the required flows (up to feedback):
import stim

circuit = stim.Circuit("""
    RZ 0 5
    MXX 1 0
    MXX 4 5
    MZZ 0 5
    MXX 2 0
    MXX 3 5
    MZ 0 5
""")
print(circuit.diagram())
print()
for e in circuit.flow_generators():
    print(e)

q0: -R-MXX--------MZZ:rec[2]-MXX--------M:rec[5]-
       |          |          |
q1: ---MXX:rec[0]-|----------|-------------------
                  |          |
q2: --------------|----------MXX:rec[3]----------
                  |
q3: --------------|----------MXX:rec[4]----------
                  |          |
q4: ---MXX:rec[1]-|----------|-------------------
       |          |          |
q5: -R-MXX--------MZZ--------MXX--------M:rec[6]-

1 -> _____Z xor rec[6]
1 -> _XXXX_ xor rec[0] xor rec[1] xor rec[3] xor rec[4]
1 -> Z_____ xor rec[5]
____X_ -> ____X_
___X__ -> ___X__
___ZZ_ -> ___ZZ_ xor rec[6]
__X___ -> __X___
__Z_Z_ -> __Z_Z_ xor rec[2] xor rec[5]
_X____ -> __XXX_ xor rec[0] xor rec[1] xor rec[3] xor rec[4]
_Z__Z_ -> _Z__Z_ xor rec[2]


I understand that one can learn the syndrome of XXXX and that this is ZX equivalent to the usual syndrome extraction circuit. The part that I wasn’t very convinced about is in the logical update using the new measurement scheme.
For example, if I consider a logical representative of the logical Z, where it has support on the X stabilizer im considering (X1X2X3X4) such that Z_L restricted to these qubits is Z1Z3, I will notice that Z1Z3 does end up still being Z1Z3 by the end of the measurement sequence for this stabilizer. However, what I am not sure about is the sign of the Z_L…

At a certain step in this sequence, I will obtain Z1Z3Za and in the next step Z1Z3Zb. This update requires multiplying in the measurement outcome from ZaZb. But the question is what if there is a measurement error for ZaZb? Since the outcome of Z1Z3Zb is the outcome of Z1Z3Za multiplied with the outcome of ZaZb, then a measurement error for ZaZb will lead to one deducing the wrong sign for the logical representative. So my question is with regards to how a single measurement error does not cause a logical error.

Note that the logical operators evolve for the Floquet code too, but that was all right, because the measurements that are being used to update the logical representatives are themselves involved in detector cells, and conveniently, the syndrome for a measurement error is the same as some low weight Pauli error in the same logical coset. So I really want to know why this measurement sequence for the surface code works, even though now the syndrome for a measurement error for ZaZb is the same as a trivial error since ZaZb is not part of any detector cell

@Jenn Multiplying the measurements into the observable will be fault tolerant, because you will also need to multiply them into the detector declarations checking on the stabilizers. It works for the same reason that floquet codes work. The key thing is that the observable travels through the gate in a way that is covered by the detectors, and the detectors interlock in essentially the same way they would for a 'black box' measurement. You may see reductions in code distance due to hook errors from where there is extra overlap between detectors.

@Jenn If you write down the full circuit as a stim circuit, with annotated detectors and observable, you can use methods like stim.Circuit.shortest_graphlike_error to verify that the circuit is fault tolerant with the expected distance.

Thanks! I really appreciate this. It is just quite error-prone to verify by hand.
